# PrestaShop - wrong conversion rate in order payment

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I have installed PrestaShop version 1.7.8.8 and the Blue Media payment module (v2.8.7).The payment generally works, but the entry is added without filling in the **payment method name** and with **conversion rate = 0**. This causes an error in the statistics. I don't know what I can configure to set these values.

[image]

On the statistics page, one of the fields from the database is `SUM(amount / conversion_rate) as total`. As a result, the total value for a given row is null.This was causing throwing an exception and the whole page would not turn on. I added a if statement in the code so now I have acceess to the rest of the statistics, but for payments the error message is displayed instead correct data.
[image]

I have set currency. And it has a conversion rate assigned to it.
[image]
Also checked in the database in ps_currency table.
[image]
In the currency restriction section, I have a currency assigned to the blue media payment module. The currency is assigned to module in table ps_module_currency.
[image]

In the table ps_blue_transactions all entries has set currency value as 'PLN'.
I also see that in ps_orders table I have correct values for both field payment and conversion_rate...

The name is less important, but in the configuration of the Blue Media module I set the name of the payment module in the shope as 'Blue Media', and an empty one is added.
[image]

I see some errors in the logs, but I don't see much information.
[image]

(I check the data in the database, but all changes were made through the admin panel, not directly into the database.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an official module from https://addons.prestashop.com/ marketplace.

Firstly please check if you have missing module translations in the back office for your currently active template. It would also be helpful to see the module settings.

Now it looks like Prestashop doesn't recognize the payment method. Either the payment method name is empty or it doesn't get properly written into the database table.

I guess we would need to see the software code of the module to debug the payment_method label function for you.

You can always fix your current orders with SQL:

```
UPDATE ps_order_payment SET payment_method = REPLACE(payment_method,'','blue_media');
```